# Precision T5810 Workstation and INTEL SSD Series 750

Tags: dell, ssd, intel, pci-express

I'm trying to spec out a Precision T5810 Workstation and install a INTEL SSD Series 750 drive in it.

According to the top rated review at http://www.amazon.co.uk/INTEL-Series-400GB-Full-Height/dp/B00VPK0NSI

> There are two types of NVM-e Express Drives Type 1 is a 2.5" Form Factor utilizing a
>   special M.2 adapter card and cable (included with drive). 
>   Type 2 is a  AIC (add-in-card) which utilizes the second PCI-e 3.0 graphics card
>   slot (recommended)

I can't work out which is best as a boot drive for the `Dell Precision T5810 Workstation`.

Does anyone know which I should choose?

Comment: This computer hasn't got an M.2 slot. So the choice is obvious.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton. Do you know if this computer is capable of getting full performance from the PCIe SSD?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I've read about the motherboard on some computers' having limited PCI bandwidth and the SSD only working at half bandwidth when there's a graphics card in there also.

Comment: This Amazon review states "The Type 2 will work in most any PCI-e slot but it will not provide a full customer experience unless pared with PCI-e 3.0 Bandwidth and with Specific X99 or Z97 Chipsets."  I'm not sure this workstation has "PCI-e 3.0 Bandwidth and with Specific X99 or Z97 Chipsets."

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty well-versed in the Intel 750 SSD and its variants. I'd recommend you use the PCIe (AIC) card for this. They function well in PCIe 2.0 environments as well, up to the bandwidth limits of the interface.